# How to get the selected element of the IOS voiceover on a webpage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, accessibility, voiceover

I couldn't find answer to this question anywhere on the web. For example we can get active element using document.activeElement in JavaScript. Is there any way to get the element focused by ios VoiceOver?

Answer (score 0):

For normal focusable elements (buttons, links, checkbox, etc), when you swipe to them, the onFocus event is run.  But for plain text, such as a `<p>` or `<h2>`, they don't receive any kind of event when you swipe to them.  You'd have to have `<p tabindex='0'>` for the `<p>` to receive an event.